# Can we use "either ... or..." after "might as well"?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

Is this example correct?

> I've been fired from my job, so I might as well either look for another job or just sit at home.

Can the construction "either... or..." (or even "whether... or..." ) come after "might/may as well"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gramatically the structure is fine, but logically it makes no sense.

"I might as well" is an idiomatic expression that can present either an *unenthusiastic* suggestion, or suggest that something is *the same* as something else.

For example:

> - I might as well start the cleaning
>     (*unenthusiastic*)
> - The wages are so low I might as well not work
>     (*suggesting that not working is the same as working for low wages*)

The issue with your example is that the two options presented are neither comparable nor unenthusiastic. Looking for a new job requires effort, but sitting at home does not.

If it were two comparable options it would make a little more sense, for example:

> I might as well either look for a new job or set up my own business.

Still, it isn't really good use of the idiom. "I might as well" means you feel resigned to something. If you still have a choice, then you aren't really resigned.

If you were to drop the idiom "I might as well" there is nothing wrong with presenting your two options together.

> I've been fired from my job, so my choices are either look for another job or just sit at home

Comment: Thank you! But can I drop the "either or" and say something like "I'm hungry, so I might as well cook something or order food from a restaurant"? Sorry if there are mistakes in my sentence

Comment: @AlekseyTyan Again... your example doesn't really use the idiom properly. If you are hungry, surely that's motivation enough to get food? One of those options requires effort, the other far less, so again they aren't really comparable. You don't use "I might as well" to present choices - it's an idiomatic expression to show lack of enthusiasm, or to compare a new option with one you are already facing.